# Auth0 email confirmation, how to handle registration gracefuly

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, jwt, auth0

I am using auth0.

My app requires users to confirm their email.

When a user registers, he receives this alert:

```
Error: unauthorized. Check the console for further details.
```

This is because the user has not yet verified his email.

How do I "catch" this event / alert in order to redirect the user to a view of my choice?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of different parts to this.

1). have you enabled the email verified rule?  (it is a template available from Auth0 dashboard -

```
function forceEmailVerification(user, context, callback) {

  console.log("force-email-verification");

  if(context.connection !== "MyDB") {
    return callback(null, user, context); 
  }

  if (!user.email_verified) {
    return callback(new UnauthorizedError('Please verify your email before logging in.'));
  } else {
    return callback(null, user, context);
  }
}
```

That effectively raises an exception in the Rules pipeline if email not verified. It will return the error to your application on the callbackUrl you provide as two query params - `error` and `error_description`. It is then up to you how you handle this - Here is a [sample Node.js application](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-node-error-handler-sample) I wrote specifically to illustrate how this works - In the sample, i am using some express middleware to check for the error and error_description and forward to a [Custom controller / view](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-node-error-handler-sample/blob/master/routes/index.js#L38) if detected.

2). Only if needed, you can also explicitly trigger an email verification email. It is a POST request to `https://{{tenant}}.auth0.com/api/users/{{user_id}}/send_verification_email`
 endpoint, passing an Authorization Bearer header with an Auth0 APIv1 token (and empty body).  The token can be obtained by making a POST request to `https://{{tenant}}.auth0.com/oauth/token` endpoint passing body of the form:

```
{
  "client_id": "{GLOBAL CLIENT ID}",
  "client_secret": "{GLOBAL CLIENT SECRET}",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

You can get the global client id and client secret under account settings -> advanced from Auth0 dashboard. Please do NOT store any secrets on SPA apps etc - using this endpoint should only be done from Client Confidential / Trusted applications (e.g traditional MVC webapp you own).

Hope this helps. Please leave comments if anything unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying this out now!

Comment: @arcseldon would you know how to retrieve the user_id in this case. I need it to trigger a resend of the email verification

Comment: Hi Kane  - are you asking how to retrieve the user_id from inside a Rule?